# Tabs in Toolbar without Viewpager in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-toolbar

I have gone through lot of answers in SO and didn't get any proper solution to implement the Tabs in Toolbar without Viewpager.

I have gone through the SlidingTabsBasic example available in sdk samples, however, that didn't meet my requirements.

Please help me to implement the Tabs in Toolbar without Viewpager.

Please don't suggest me to use Viewpager, because my app should not support that as per the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, we have android support design library to implement the Tabs using [android.support.design.widget.TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). Here is the snapshot of code. Hope this will help for someone.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));

            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    //load fragment or do whatever you want
                    Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
                    getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerLayout, fragment).commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Im still tryna find the kotlin version of of the setOnTabSelectedListener() function.

Answer (score 2):

> Please help me to implement the Tabs in Toolbar without Viewpager.

[The `Toolbar` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) does not support any form of tabs, with or without a `ViewPager`.

If you want a tabbed UI, and you do not want to use `ViewPager`, you are welcome to use `FragmentTabHost` or create your own tab UI yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check with the FragmentTabHost.